# How do I incorporate IFERROR into this formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to know how to include an `IFERROR` statement in this formula in Excel 2007.

```
=VLOOKUP($E3,HSA!$E$3:$G$20,2,FALSE)*$D3
```

I want the formula to return a `0` instead of an `#N/A`.

Comment: =IFERROR(your_formula,0)  leave out the = from the beginning of your formula when you embed it.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand.  What would my formula look like with your formula embedded in it?

Comment: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E3,HSA!$E$3:$G$20,2,FALSE)*$D3,0)